# Question about finite rank operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $X$ be a normed space, $\mathcal{F}(X)$ the algebra of all operators on $X$ with finite fank, then $\mathcal{F}(X)$ is the unique minimal ideal of $\mathcal{K}(X)$ the algebra of all compact operators on $X$.

I want to show that any non-zero ideal $\cal{I}$ of $\mathcal{K}(X)$ necessarily contains all operators with rank one. But I can not show a rank one operator $P$ can be written as $AT$, where $T\in\cal{I}$, $A\in\mathcal{K}(X)$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just some ideas: if $\cal{I}$ is an arbitrary non-zero ideal, it seems that all you know a priori is that $\cal{I}$ contains _some_ nonzero operator $B$. The rank of $B$ must be at least one. Can you compose $B$ with a compact operator to obtain a rank one operator $C$? Then to obtain an arbitrary rank one operator $P$, maybe compose $C$ with what I want to call a "rotation". (I keep wanting to assume we're in a Hilbert space, since things seem more natural to me there!)

Comment: Thank you very much. your "rotation" inspires me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a normed space, by $\mathcal{F}(X)$ we denote the space of finite rank operators on $X$. For a given $x\in X$ and $f\in X^*$ we define rank one operator
$x\bigcirc f:X\to X:z\mapsto f(z)x$. One can show that $\mathcal{F}(X)=\operatorname{span}\{x\bigcirc f: x\in X, f\in X^*\}$.

> Every non-zero two sided ideal of $\mathcal{B}(X)$ of a normed space $X$ contains $\mathcal{F}(X)$

**Proof.** Let $I$ be a non-zero two sided ideal of $\mathcal{B}(X)$. Consider $T\in I\setminus\{0\}$, then there is $x_0\in X$ such that $T(x_0)\neq 0$. By Hahn-Banach theorem there exist $f_0\in X^*$ such that  $f(x_0)=1$. Now consider arbitrary rank one operator $x\bigcirc f$ where $x\in X$ and $f\in X^*$. Note that $x\bigcirc f=(x\bigcirc f_0)T(x_0\bigcirc f)$, but $T\in I$, so $x\bigcirc f\in I$. Now by previous remark $\mathcal{F}(X)\subset I$.